# Checking if local storage has object inside in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have built an website with routes, and I'm using localstorage to transfer data between routes.

So I have created `onClick` handler that storage the data in localstorage using `JSON.stringify` like this:

```
const [build, setBuild] = useState({section: ['build']});
const [promote, setPromote] = useState({section: ['promote']});
const [ad, setAd] = useState({section: []});


 //..later on function that save localstorage and route to another page

localStorage.setItem('buildObject', JSON.stringify(build));
localStorage.setItem('adObject', JSON.stringify(ad));
localStorage.setItem('promoteObject', JSON.stringify(promote));
```

Next I'm luring the data from the storage like this:

```
useEffect(() => {
   //Check if buildObject isn't empty
   if (JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('buildObject')) !== null) {
       //Do something
   }
   if (JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('promoteObject')) !== null) {
       //Do something
   }
   if (JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('adObject')) !== null) {
       //Do something
   }
}, []);
```

The problem is, that even if `ad` state is empty, it presents himselfs as not empty, and the if statement overrides.

How can I check if localstorage has object inside and if it's empty?

Comment: `ad` state is not empty, it contains an object `{section: []}`

Comment: @EdgarHenriquez yes that's why I'm asking how to check if local storage has empty object inside.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have set `localStorage.setItem('adObject', JSON.stringify(ad))` is object has empty data; You will get `JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('adObject'))` the same the thing you have set before. Just check,

```
const adStorage = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('adObject'));
if (adStorage !== null && adStorage.section.length) {
    //Do something
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using `for in` loop:

```
const adData = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('adObject'));

for (const property in adData) {
    if (ad.property.length) {
        // do something
    }
}
```